# Getting image file thumbnaiil with oauth_token parameter

Tags: images, url

I am trying to get the thumbnail for an image that has been posted as a file to the chatter. I have been able to do this for a User Profile image by sending &oauth_token=(my oauth token) as a query parameter, but cannot get it to work for the image thumbnails.

The Url i am trying to use is the renditionUrl240By180 property on the attachment item.

I have a url that looks like this:

[https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/chatter/files/069i0000001S2RvAAK/rendition?type=THUMB240BY180&oauth_token=(my](https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/chatter/files/069i0000001S2RvAAK/rendition?type=THUMB240BY180&oauth_token=%28my) oauth token).

When i send this i get the following response:
 

INVALID_SESSION_ID
Session expired or invalid

Answer (score 0):

You access_token that you got via the OAuth process must have either the **web** or **full** scope in the connected app.

[Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193348&language=en_US&type=1)